# time complexity of a search function

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

i am writing  the function search Matrix to check if the given value is included in the matrix in O(N) time. This matrix has the following properties:•Integers in each row are sorted in ascending from left to right.•Integers in each column are sorted in ascending from top to bottom

```
public boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target) {
        if(matrix==null || matrix.length==0 || matrix[0].length==0) 
            return false;

        int m = matrix.length;
        int n = matrix[0].length;

        int start = 0;
        int end = m*n-1;

        while(start<=end){
            int mid=(start+end)/2;
            int midX=mid/n;
            int midY=mid%n;

            if(matrix[midX][midY]==target) 
                return true;

            if(matrix[midX][midY]<target){
                start=mid+1;
            }else{
                end=mid-1;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

i want to know if this function has complexity of O(N)

Comment: What is N for you ?

Comment: This [link](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html) may help you.